# ASK CakePHP - work with password field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have searched many topic in here but I can't solve my problem. Please check this for me.

I made the register page and when I made for password field...

I had **users_controller.php** like:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    var $name = "Users";
    var $helpers = array('Paginator','Html');
    var $paginate = array();

    //Doi tuong component de thuc thi thao tac login
    public $components = array
    (
        'Auth' => array
        (
            'authorize' => 'controller',
            'loginRedirect' => array
            (
                'admin' => FALSE,
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'dashboard' 
            ),
            'loginError' => 'Invalid account',
            'authError' => 'You don\'t have permission'
        ),
    'Session'   
    );

    //Ham loc cac user truoc khi truy cap trang
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
        $this->Auth->allow('viewuserall');
    }

    //Ham them moi user
    public function add()
    {
        $this->layout = 'TDCake';

        $this->User->set($this->data);
        if($this->User->valid_user() == TRUE)
        {
            if(!empty($this->data))
            {
                $this->User->create();
                if($this->User->save($this->data))
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('User has been created!');
                        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Please correct the errors');
                    }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Your data is NOT available");
        }
    }

    //Ham login cho user
    public function login()
    {
        $this->layout = 'TDCake';
        if
        (
            !empty($this->data) &&
            !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['username'])&&
            !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['password'])
        )
        {
            $user = $this->User->find
            (
                'first',array
                (
                    'conditions'=>array
                        (
                            'User.email'=>$this->Auth->data['User']['username'],
                            'User.password'=>$this->Auth->data['User']['password']
                        ),
                    'recursive' => -1
                )
            );
            if(!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user))
            {
                if($this->Auth->autoRedirect)
                {
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash
                (
                    $this->Auth->loginError,
                    $this->Auth->flashElement,
                    array(),'auth'
                );
            }
        }
    }

    //Ham logout cho user
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }   

    //Ham gi cha biet, de do tinh sau =))
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $this->layout = 'TDCake';

    }

    //Ham view cac user khong dieu kien trong table users
    function viewuserall()
    {
        $this->layout = 'TDCake';
        $this->paginate=array
        (
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array('id' => 'asc'),
        );
        $data = $this->paginate("User");
        $this->set("data",$data);
    }

}
```

**User.php** in Model is:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $name = "User";
    var $validate = array();

    function validate_passwords()
    {
        if($this->data[$this->alias]['pass'] == $this->data[$this->alias]['rpass'])
        { 
            return $this->data[$this->alias]['pass'] = $this->data['User']['password'];
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }

    function valid_user()
    {
        $this->validate = array
        (
            //Kiem tra username truoc khi add
            'username' => array
            (
                'rule01_notEmpty' => array
                (
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'You must enter your Username !'
                ),
                'rule02_max16' => array
                (
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 20), 
                    'message' => 'Your Username must be less than 20 chars !'
                ),
                'rule03_exists' => array
                (
                    'rule' => 'isUnique', 
                    'message' => 'Your Username have already existed !'
                )
            ),
            //Kiem tra email truoc khi add
            'email' => array
            (
                'rule01_notEmpty' => array
                (
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'You must enter your Email !'
                ),
                'rule02_exists' => array
                (
                    'rule' => 'isUnique', 
                    'message' => 'Your Email have already existed !'
                ),
                'rule03_emailtype' => array
                (
                    'rule' => 'email', 
                    'message' => 'You didn\'t type a email !'
                )                   
            ),
            //Kiem tra password truoc khi add
            'pass' => array
            (
                'length' => array
                (
                    'rule'      => array('between', 6, 20),
                    'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
                ),
            ),
            'rpass' => array
            (
                'length' => array
                (
                    'rule'      => array('between', 6, 20),
                    'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
                ),
                'compare' => array
                (
                    'rule'    => 'validate_passwords',
                    'message' => 'The passwords you entered do not match.',
                )
            )
        );//End this->validate=array


        if($this->validates($this->validate==TRUE))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//End function valid_user

}
```

**add.ctp** is

```
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => ('Username')));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => ('Email')));
echo $this->Form->input('pass', array('label' => ('Password'),'type' => 'password', 'value' => ''));
echo $this->Form->input('rpass', array('label' => ('Repeat Password'), 'type' => 'password', 'value' => ''));
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('label' =>('Firstname')));
echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('label' =>('Lastname')));
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array('label' =>('DOB'),'type' => 'date'));


echo $this->Form->end('Register');
```

*Explanation:* 
So, in this case, I can validate 2 Password Fields (empty, not equal,...), but it can't insert to the database. That mean it INSERTED current data into the DB but password column in DB is EMPTY. In database, my password column name "password" also.

In another case, I change the name "pass" into "password" for the

```
echo $this->Form->input('pass', array(
```

Of course, I have changed any place related to...

and in that case, it can be inserted the password but can not validate anything.

**I am too confused about this...I don't know what I am wrong is....can anybody help me.**

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/). This can also be useful if you are a beginner and are afraid of making sth wrong.

Comment: Sorry I đon't understand your means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are doing an assignment in your validate function:

```
   return $this->data[$this->alias]['pass'] = $this->data['User']['password'];
```

And even if you were doing an assignment, it should be:

```
   return $this->data['User']['password'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['pass'];
```

Realize that the field "password" is getting the value from `$this->data` which has the information, not the other way around.

Also. It would be better (in terms of clarity), to break this code in two lines.

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['pass'];
return $this->data['User']['password'];
```

You should name your field the exact name "password" if that's what it is called in the database **AND** if you are not explicitly assigning it.

Your add function is not doing the above, and further more, as a best practice, you should be hashing the password.

See the CakePHP book on tutorials and examples.

Take some time to go through it with all the snippets and recommendations. And don't forget the standards. :)

Comment: Thank you, I go through this problem. Now it's just a little one. The my "rpass" is tell error. How can I ignore this field when it insert to the DB.

Comment: You can use "unset($data['field']);" to remove the field right before saving.

Comment: I have tried but it will be the Blank Parameter and it will insert null data into the DB. But in my DB didn't have column looks like this name. That cause it made that error. I just want to ask How to ignore the parameter rpass when the it prepare to save. Please ! T_T

Comment: I don't think I understand you. You want to ignore "rpass", but yet you want the value to be inserted in the database.. ?? Mind Blow.

Comment: I guess your intention is to save rpass -> password, as such, assign the value: $user['User']['password'] = $data['User']['rpass'];, then save

Comment: No. I mean: when it passed all validations, the data will be inserted into database BUT it's include the "rpass" into the SQL query and it shows the ERROR (because in my DB didn't have rpass column) => I want to ignore the rpass out of the parameter before it make the query to insert to the DB.